# Calendar ID in create response differs from what Graph stores

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are experiencing inconsistencies with calendar ID's.

When sending a POST to `https://graph.mircrosoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars` with the following payload

```
{ name: 'Calendar' }
```

We receive this reponse from which we store the id

```
{
 :"@odata.context"=>"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('user%40outlook.com')/calendars/$entity",
 :id=>"AQMkADAwATMwMAItMjE5ZC01YjYyLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA1D6u4KwtRdMm1rAZoOEKvAHAMf0BP7S_89KmnrxCgze9tcAAAIBBgAAAMf0BP7S_89KmnrxCgze9tcAAAEBKdoAAAA=",
  :name=>"Calendar", 
  :color=>"auto", 
  :changeKey=>"x/QE/tL7z0qaevEKDN721wAAAAAOFQ==", 
  :canShare=>true, 
  :canViewPrivateItems=>true, 
  :canEdit=>true, 
  :owner=>{:name=>"User", :address=>"user@outlook.com"}
}
```

When we attempt to create events into this calendar errors are being thrown as that ID does not exist. Looking into it further and making a GET request to `https://graph.mircrosoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars` we receive this payload (truncated for brevity)

```
{
  :id=>"AQMkADAwATMwMAItMjE5ZC01YjYyLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA1D6u4KwtRdMm1rAZoOEKvAHAMf0BP7S_89KmnrxCgze9tcAAAIBBgAAAMf0BP7S_89KmnrxCgze9tcAAAIjxAAAAA==",
  :name=>"Calendar",
  :color=>"auto", 
  :changeKey=>"I8E7t/aNjEqDHtJJL1UC6AAADFI=", 
  :canShare=>true, 
  :canViewPrivateItems=>true, 
  :canEdit=>true, 
  :owner=>{:name=>"User", :address=>"user@outlook.com"}}]
}
```

After diffing both ID's, we notice they differ. The interesting part of this is that this only happens with a handful of users and isn't an issue with most accounts. Is there a better way to keep track of specific calendars that we can continue to sync into? I'd hate to have to ping for calendars every time we'd like to fire off a CRUD action.

Comment: Have you tried using a name other than "Calendar"?

Comment: Yes, 'Calendar' is just a placeholder for what we actually use. Our calendar naming convention is '<company name> <timestamp>'.